# UILabel right next to UIImage using autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uilabel, swift2

How would I go about creating a layout like this using autolayout?

[image]
The icon is UIImage, text is UILabel.

The label text can vary in width, but will always be single-line. How do I force the label to scale with the text horizontally and UIImage to be immediately to the left of the label?

I have tried using attributedText. I also tried views as containers and a horizontal stack view, but failed to get the result I wanted. What are the other options?

Comment: Are you using `UIStoryBoard` to apply constraints?

Comment: Yes, I am applying the constraints on the storyboard.

Comment: In this case, I will use `UIButton` directly. It has a left image icon, and right text. And set its `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` for disable any touch events.

Comment: Should work with `UIStackView`.

Comment: Toro answer would be great for this case, however, u can set the uiimage to have the aspect ratio as u like, then choose both label and uiimage and set equal height, then they will be same no matter how big the label change, also set the middle constraint for them ofc

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set the width and height constraint for the image when you used `UIStackView`. I have a few examples with images in my [UIStackView-Playground](https://github.com/dasdom/UIStackViewPlayground). I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went for a solution where I added a third view as the leftmost element in a horizontal stackview and set the stackview's distribution as 'equal centering'. It actually fit well with the rest of the planned layout (all elements are used efficiently). Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

That should be absolutely no problem - just put in the image, make layout constraints to the left and top of the view, then add the label right to it, and make **layout constraints between the right side of the image and the left side of the text**.

To restrict the label width you can add a constraint from the right side of the label to the right side of the view, if you want to make the label as small as possible with a `greater-than` sign.

EDIT

If the whole should be bound to the right border of the superview, put both in a view, align the view to the right border of the superview, and make a constraint from the right side of the label to the right side of the view. The view will resize accordingly when the label resizes.

Comment: I forgot to add that the whole thing should be aligned to the right.

Comment: That's indeed important info :-).